# How to add a rule to the Zend URL mapping and compose multiple MVC paths?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-framework-routing

This is because I want to develop a web platform with more than one application in the same project.

---

In any MVC web application we should have this default URL schema:

`domain`/`controller`/`action`/`parameters`

**1:** In Zend, what can I do (in which files) to change this schema to add the `application` name before the `controller` name?

Expected Result: `domain`/`application`/`controller`/`action`/`parameters`

**2:** How can I implement the consequences of this new URL block in terms that I will separate the MVC for each application, maintaining the shared resources in a separate directory? What changes may I do in Zend `autoloader`

Expected Result:

```
/public_html/
/public_html/platform
/public_html/platform/apps

/public_html/platform/apps/base (user interface container)

/public_html/platform/apps/crm
/public_html/platform/apps/crm/model
/public_html/platform/apps/crm/view
/public_html/platform/apps/crm/control
/public_html/platform/apps/crm/public
/public_html/platform/apps/crm/public/css (and etc.)

/public_html/platform/apps/erp
/public_html/platform/apps/erp/model
/public_html/platform/apps/erp/view
/public_html/platform/apps/erp/control
/public_html/platform/apps/erp/public
/public_html/platform/apps/erp/public/js (and etc.)

/public_html/platform/sys
/public_html/platform/sys/core
/public_html/platform/sys/cfg

/public_html/platform/libs/
/public_html/platform/libs/zend
/public_html/platform/libs/template_it
/public_html/platform/libs/custom
```

Comment: First things first: Are you using ZF1 or ZF2?

Comment: @STLMikey I intend to use latest ZF2 but if this situation gets two difficult, I may build a simple MVC and use some Zend libs, specially for DB and PDF.

Comment: Each individual module in ZF2 defines it's own routing structure in the module's module.config file. If there is shared structure needed across modules, the application.config is where you will put those.

Comment: Why is your PHP code in a subfolder of "public HTML"?

Comment: Will be there or will be in in the same *ancestor* directory...

Comment: @STLMikey but what about the controllers, views and models routes?

Comment: Come on guys, help me out! ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think it is as easy as having actual different ZF2 application, every one in its own folder, and in the same level, a "vendor" folder where you put all the shared structure (coming from zend, third party libraries, etc).

Then inside the vendor folder, i would create another folder for your own shared code, including all your  modules that has to be used by more than one of the applications, so your code is a library for yourself.

Since your app is actually in domain/application, and everyone has it own config, it is very straightforward to have  `domain/application/controller/action/parameters` routes: you just create  your normal  `controller/action/parameters` routes, since the app actually resides in `domain/application/` and the router doesnt have to care about it.

As you noticed, another problem is the autoloader. YOu just need to update the references to the shared modules inside your `application.config.php` for everyone of your apps

```
return array(
    'modules' => array( //....
    ),
    'module_listener_options' => array(
        'config_glob_paths'    => array(
            'config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php'
        ),
        'config_cache_enabled' => false,
        'cache_dir'            => 'data/cache',
        'module_paths' => array(
            './module',
            '../vendor',//reference to your library modules
        ),
    ),
  //...
);
```

of course, if the modules doesnt reside directly inside `vendor/module` but something like `vendor/libraryname/module`, you have to take a look at your autoload system (Composer autoloading or whatever) and add the classes or namespaces to the corresponding maps.